# 2D array iteration speed in swift (Beta 4)

Tags: arrays, swift, iteration, beta

I've been battling with speed issues in Swift, mainly with arrays. Currently running with latest 'beta 4' release. I've broken the code out into playground to try and show the issues

I setup an 2D array, the iterate over it, set each element.

```
import UIKit

func getCurrentMillitime() -> NSTimeInterval {
    let date: NSDate = NSDate()
    return date.timeIntervalSince1970*1000;
}

let startTime = getCurrentMillitime()

let X = 40
let Y = 50
var distanceGrid = [[CGFloat]](count: X, repeatedValue:[CGFloat](count: Y,repeatedValue:CGFloat(0.0)))
for xi in 0..<X {
    for yi in 0..<Y {
        distanceGrid[xi][yi] = 1.1
       //println("x:\(xi) y:\(yi) d:\(distanceGrid[xi][yi])")
    }
}

let endTime = getCurrentMillitime()
let computationTime = endTime - startTime
println("Time to compute \(computationTime) ms")
```

Run the above code and you'll get :

```
Time to compute 2370.203125 ms
```

Which sure can't be right !.. Am I being a numpty ?

Comment: +1 to use of the word 'numpty' (but surely you are not)!

Comment: that is odd... in _beta4_ I've got significantly faster runtime: _"Time to compute 72.72509765625 ms"_. that code looks about 30x faster in my computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that the Swift beta is struggling with arrays.
Even with a one-dimensional array, compared to objective-c the difference is huge.

I've mixed a objC class into a swift program and had both languages create and alter an array of 1,000,000 elements. This is what I got on some MacBook:

Elapsed time by Swift method: 2.7078 sec
Elapsed time by objective-c method: 0.033815 seconds

Code:  ( var nrOfElements = 1000000 )

```
  // Swift
    let startTime = NSDate();
    var stringList = Array<String>(count: nrOfElements, repeatedValue:String())
    for i in 0..<nrOfElements {
      stringList[i] = "Some string";
    }
    let endTime = NSDate();
    println("Elapsed time by Swift method: " +
      NSString(format:"%.4f", endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)) + " sec");

   // Objective-c
      NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
      NSMutableArray *stringList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
      for (int i = 0; i < nrOfElements; i++) {
        [stringList addObject:@"Some string"];
      }
      NSDate *endTime = [NSDate date];
      printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Elapsed time by objective-c method: %f seconds", [endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime]] UTF8String]);
```

- I found no difference between Beta-3 and Beta-4, so improving
  array-handling isn't high on the priority list.
- Processing increasingly larger arrays, give proportional higher process times.
- Handling multi-dimensional arrays is even more costly when increasing the number of higher dimension elements
- Pre-creation of the array in Swift is indeed faster than 'append'

Let's hope that things adequately will be repaired in the final version.

Comment: Thanks for pretty much clarifying my findings, seems a shame to have such a fundamental part of a language lag behind .. beta or not, I'm struggling to figure out why after 4yrs or so, arrays are still being wrapped in cotton wool !

Comment: Your benchmarks no longer appear to be correct as of beta 5. When I run your above Swift and Objective-C code, I get 0.050875 s for Swift and 0.040739 s for Objective-C using the -O optimization for Swift (what would be used for a Release build) and -Os for Objective-C (on a 2012 i7 Retina MBP). You might want to re-run these tests.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to consider about Swift performance:

- It's very much up in the air during the beta.
- Many of Swift's performance tricks depend on the optimizer. Especially when generics are involved (every array is a generic `Array<T>`), Swift uses a more expressive / debugger-friendly implementation at `-O0`, but optimizes it away to a higher-performance implementation at `-O` or `-Ofast`. (Note that `-Ofast` also takes away bounds checks and other safety features, so it's not a great idea for production builds.)

Also, note your current example is measuring both the time to create a 2D array with `init(count:repeatedValue:` and the time to iterate it. If you're out to measure only the latter, you should set your `startTime` after creating the arrays.

Comment: Totally understand the 'beta' status, just wondering if others are seeing similar...

Answer (score 0):

In the language guide under "subscripts", you'll find a 2D (struct) implementation of a 2D array. But it is rather slow in assigning values if you go above a 1000 elements.

Creating a local 2D array and setting it into the struct for easy acces is much faster.

It's also faster to create an array with repeated values and overwrite them than to append values to an array.

For about 100k values it takes ~9seconds with the struct, 1.5 seconds with the append and 0.6 seconds with overwriting repeated values.

I kinda like the struct idea, but it is so slow.
I sure hope it's a beta issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that even a beta version cannot behave like software of the eighties on hardware of the seventies. So I did some more digging into the Swift array-handling capabilities and I stumbled upon astonishing results. We learned already that the Swift array performance is poor when compared to objective-c or other languages as c++, c#, java, etc.

In my previous tests I measured the time to create and fill a local scope array of one million elements. As we saw, objective-c did this about 80 times faster. Worse it gets when we compare arrays declared in global class scope. Then objC appears to be about 500 times faster!

But hey, when we finally have filled up this global declared array with useful data, we can smoothly work with it right? Wrong!

I’ve printed 10 elements of the large array and the nightmare deepened. The 10 elements of a local scope array took 0,0004 seconds, as may be expected. But printing the same elements of our global declared array took… 1 minute and 11 seconds. This seems too bad to be true and I’m sure the Swift developers are on it as we speak.